# Compare all elements of a set with a specific number and return 1 or 0

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols

Say I generate a set of 20 random numbers by x=RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20], I want to compare every element of x with 0.4. If it is less than or equal to 0.4, then return 1; if it is greater than 0.4, then return 0. Seems "If" does not work on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: `Boole[# <= 0.4] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
x = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
t = .4;
```

You can also use [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) or [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) or [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) as follows:

```
result1  = UnitStep[t - x];
result2  = Boole[# <= t] & /@ x;
result3  = Round @ Clip[x, {t, t}, {1, 0}];

Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{x, result1, result2, result3}], 
   {"x", "UnitStep[t-x]", "Boole[#≤t]&/@x", "Round@Clip[x, {t,t},{1,0}]"}], 
   Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: That's wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, one more question. If the result <= 0.4, then return 1; if 0.4< result <=0.7, then return 2; if  0.7< result <=1, then return 3. Could you show it?

Comment: @LeslieChiu, try [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

Comment: I did not work out. Could you show the coding as above? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try `Map[(If[# <= 0.4, 1, 0]) &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]]`!

Comment: I tried this: X = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]
Y = Map[(If[X <= 0.4, 1, 0])]
then it shows as follow:
{0.854999, 0.770654, 0.534591, 0.0626347, 0.992642, 0.257361, \
0.111395, 0.26624, 0.181177, 0.420816, 0.481545, 0.477984, \
0.00108653, 0.283569, 0.0236485, 0.163868, 0.115088, 0.892581, \
0.151478, 0.32152}

Map[If[{0.854999, 0.770654, 0.534591, 0.0626347, 0.992642, 0.257361, 
    0.111395, 0.26624, 0.181177, 0.420816, 0.481545, 0.477984, 
    0.00108653, 0.283569, 0.0236485, 0.163868, 0.115088, 0.892581, 
    0.151478, 0.32152} <= 0.4, 1, 0]]

Comment: It could be correct if the answers are : {0, 0, 0, 1...}

Answer (score 4):

@LeslieChiu

Follow @kglr suggestion

```
Clear["`*"];
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, x <= 0.4}, {2, 0.4 < x <= 0.7}, {3, 
     0.7 < x <= 1}}];
f /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20]
```

Comment: Great. You two professional answers help a lot for a new beginner.

Comment: Could you explain how to get the formula and plot the discrete r.v. when P{X=1}=0.1, P{X=2}=0.3, P{X=3}=0.4, P{X=4}=0.2.